# NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, kvm, cpu

I'm using `kvm` on Ubuntu 16.04

my machine cpu is 24 core and I run 47 sandbox using hyperthreading on `kvm`.
The virtual machine use 0.5 core physically

After a few minutes of running `kvm`, the following message pops up.

I entered `iostat`, it comes out

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          46.42    0.00    5.87    6.87    0.00   40.83
```

my kernel is 4.4.0-38-generic

Please tell me what causes this kind of error (CPU lockup), and what should my next steps be?

[image: error message]